Subsetting dataframe so as to retain combinations that contain all values for a certain variable in R
Let us generate the dataframe we want to subset
vDates = 
  seq(
    from = as.Date("2024-01-01"),
    to = as.Date("2024-01-5"),
    by = 1
  )
vToy = c(1, 2, 3)
vColors = c("Blue", "Red")

tExpand = expand.grid(date = vDates, toy = vToy, col = vColors)
vRemove = c(2, 5, 25)

tTable = tExpand[- vRemove, ]
rownames(tTable) = 1 : nrow(tTable)

On 2024-01-02 and 2024-01-05 we don't have any blue toys of type 1, whereas on 2024-01-04 we don't have any red toys of type 2. How can we filter the table to extract for all dates the toys that are present in both blue and red colors and obtain the desired outcome tDesired preferably using dplyr?
tDesired = tTable[- c(15, 18, 8), ]


Another approach is to check if all of both colors are contained in col, grouped by both date and toy or type.
library(tidyverse)

tTable |>
  filter(
    all(c("Red", "Blue") %in% col),
    .by = c(date, toy)
  )

Output
         date toy  col
1  2024-01-01   1 Blue
2  2024-01-03   1 Blue
3  2024-01-04   1 Blue
4  2024-01-01   2 Blue
5  2024-01-02   2 Blue
6  2024-01-03   2 Blue
7  2024-01-04   2 Blue
8  2024-01-01   3 Blue
9  2024-01-02   3 Blue
10 2024-01-03   3 Blue
11 2024-01-04   3 Blue
12 2024-01-05   3 Blue
13 2024-01-01   1  Red
14 2024-01-03   1  Red
15 2024-01-04   1  Red
16 2024-01-01   2  Red
17 2024-01-02   2  Red
18 2024-01-03   2  Red
19 2024-01-04   2  Red
20 2024-01-01   3  Red
21 2024-01-02   3  Red
22 2024-01-03   3  Red
23 2024-01-04   3  Red
24 2024-01-05   3  Red


An approach using inner_join on the split data set
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

splt <- split(tTable, tTable$col)

inner_join(splt$Blue, splt$Red, c("date", "index")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(date, index), values_to="col") %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  arrange(col, index)

output
# A tibble: 24 × 3
   date       index col  
   <date>     <dbl> <fct>
 1 2024-01-01     1 Blue 
 2 2024-01-03     1 Blue 
 3 2024-01-04     1 Blue 
 4 2024-01-01     2 Blue 
 5 2024-01-02     2 Blue 
 6 2024-01-03     2 Blue 
 7 2024-01-04     2 Blue 
 8 2024-01-01     3 Blue 
 9 2024-01-02     3 Blue 
10 2024-01-03     3 Blue 
11 2024-01-04     3 Blue 
12 2024-01-05     3 Blue 
13 2024-01-01     1 Red  
14 2024-01-03     1 Red  
15 2024-01-04     1 Red  
16 2024-01-01     2 Red  
17 2024-01-02     2 Red  
18 2024-01-03     2 Red  
19 2024-01-04     2 Red  
20 2024-01-01     3 Red  
21 2024-01-02     3 Red  
22 2024-01-03     3 Red  
23 2024-01-04     3 Red  
24 2024-01-05     3 Red

Data
tTable <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19723, 19725, 19726, 19723, 
19724, 19725, 19726, 19727, 19723, 19724, 19725, 19726, 19727, 
19723, 19724, 19725, 19726, 19727, 19723, 19724, 19725, 19726, 
19723, 19724, 19725, 19726, 19727), class = "Date"), index = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3), col = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Blue", "Red"), class = "factor")), out.attrs = list(
    dim = c(date = 5L, index = 3L, col = 2L), dimnames = list(
        date = c("date=2024-01-01", "date=2024-01-02", "date=2024-01-03", 
        "date=2024-01-04", "date=2024-01-05"), index = c("index=1", 
        "index=2", "index=3"), col = c("col=Blue", "col=Red"))), row.names = c(NA, 
27L), class = "data.frame")

